# Why/when to set C-hat to the dispersion parameter in Quasi-AIC

Tags: r, aic, mumin

In the documentation for [MuMIn::QIAC](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/0.13.21/topics/QAIC), and several other sources on calculating QAIC, the following code snippet appears which I don't understand at all.

`dd <- dredge(budworm.lg, rank = "QAIC", chat = summary(budworm.lg)$dispersion)`

As far as I understand, chat (or c-hat, $\hat{C}$) is the VIF (variance inflation factor) - but why would you set the VIF to be the dispersion parameter?

Comment: Isn't this about the symbol used for the dispersion? The dispersion parameter in a quasi-binomial / quasi-poisson is often denoted by $\phi$. (Example: [How does one compare two nested quasibinomial GLMs?](https://tinyurl.com/r3vhebw5)); note that the log likelihood has the form $\left[y_i\theta_i - \gamma(\theta_i)\right] / \phi + \tau$ where $\tau$ is not a function of $\theta_i$. In reference to the AIC, the same parameter is sometimes denoted by $\hat{c}$. (Example: [Overdispersion in Model selection procedures (AIC)](https://tinyurl.com/wj9z3byn)); QAIC = $-2\log(L(\theta)/\hat{c}) + 2k$.